# Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to see why I am getting this issue.

```
Private Sub test()

Dim Row As Integer

For Row = 1 To 100

   'Loop through SummaryRange and ignore blanks but get document type'
    Dim documentTypes As String

    Dim myDocument As String, Column As Integer

    Column = 2

   'First get range from Summary'
    Sheets("Sheet1").Active

    If ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, Column).Value <> "" Then documentTypes = documentTypes + "," + ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, Column).Value

    Sheets("Sheet12").Active

    ActiveSheet.Range("B17").Value = documentTypes

Next Row

End Sub
```

I am trying to loop through a range in a different worksheet, then getting the values and then concatenate them into a string and output that string.

Edit:

Removed SummaryRange, gets rid of out of range issue, but brings up a `Object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: What line of the VBA is generating the error?  `SummaryRange.Range("Row:Column").Value` doesn't look right to me, you should have to actually specify the Row and Column values.

Comment: Row Column is essentially, i and j, I edited it ignore SummaryRange that shouldnt be there like that. Since the change I am getting:

Comment: object doesn't support this method or property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
 Sheets("Sheet1").Active
```

To:

```
 Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
```

The same is true for:

```
 Sheets("Sheet12").Active
```

Comment: As a side note, I also strongly suggest that you refer to the sheets using their object name. Instead of:
Sheets("Sheet12")
simply write:
Sheet12
You can change the object name of a sheet by editing the "(Name)" property of the sheet in VBA Editor.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
SummaryRange.Range("Row:Column").Value
```

to

```
SummaryRange.Range(Row:Column).Value
```

Update: try the following

```
Dim range As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set range = Range("B1:B100")

For Each row In range.Rows
   For Each cell in row.Cells

      'processing code
      'documentTypes = documentTypes + "," + cell.Value

      'etc...

   Next cell
Next row
```

Comment: Nadaa it should be `ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, Column).Value` anyway. Good spot. Although I still get same issue :(

Answer (score 1):

While bouvierr has answered your existing issue I note you can actually avoid the loop and do this more efficiently

This line
`strOut = Join(Application.Transpose(ws.Range("B1:B100")), ",")`
produces a string of all the values from B1:B100 separated by commas

As some values may be empty the resulting string may look like something like this
`test,1,2,3,,,3,,afaff,,,,,,,,,,,`

So I have used a regular expression to clean up multiple `,` into a single `'`

```
Sub QuickGrab()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim objRegex
Dim strOut As String

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
strOut = Join(Application.Transpose(ws.Range("B1:B100")), ",")

Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Pattern = ",{2,}"
    .Global = True
    strOut = .Replace(strOut, ",")
End With

MsgBox strOut
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this taught me a bundle :D